# issue with parallel processing in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

i need help on how to call a soap service in parallel. i have consumer which send requests in json and calls a soap service. soap service is old and cant be changed now.
we are using mule to do json to xml transformation before calling the soap service and xml to json before sending the response to consumer.

consumer will send input josn something like this

```
{
   "conId":"1234",
   "cliId":"9999",
   "components":[
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
   ]
}
```

and we will convert that json into 3  xml , as components attribute is array,like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <conId>1234</conId>
            <cliId>9999</cliId>
            <caseComponents>a</caseComponents>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <conId>1234</conId>
            <cliId>9999</cliId>
            <caseComponents>b</caseComponents>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <conId>1234</conId>
            <cliId>9999</cliId>
            <caseComponents>c</caseComponents>
```

those are just sample json and xml, but the issue is how do i call the soap service in parallel, i dont want to call the soap service and wait for the response , than make a second call. i want to call the soap service in parallel, aggregate the response and send back aggregated response to consumer.

scatter gather will not work in my case, i was looking into vm but it says intra-JVM communication and not sure how to apply in my use case.

can anyone suggest me good approach or if i need to use VM, how do it. i am new to Mule so do not have knowledge about all features available in mule.

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, why do you think that the scatter-gather would not work in your case? Also, have you tried using a collection-splitter - aggregator combination?